# Highlight text in djvu document

Tags: format, document, highlight, djvu

I have some books in 'djvu' format and would like to use highlighting like in 'pdf' documents. I have done some research, but without success. Is it possible to highlight text in 'djvu' documents? Also include the platform for your suggestion.